# javac incompatible types error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, types, javac, incompatibletypeerror

While compiling the code I get an unexpected error, which never occurred before, it says that I cannot convert from int to an Object...

Code:

```
maxBundles = max;
    bundleProgressBar.setMaximum(max);
    bundleProgressLabel.setText("Updating Components...");
    // Tell JS that the state is Installing.
    Object[] arr = { 1 };
```

error:

```
`103: error: incompatible types
[javac]         Object[] arr = { 1 };`
```

I know this is a problem with eclipse, because it worked before, so my question is what can I change to resolve it...

Comment: In Eclipse try Project -> Clean, make sure your project is selected

Comment: I cleaned it, and also the java builder is selected..

Comment: Whats the compiler version used. (Right Click Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler)

Comment: I remember there is a version of the eclipse compiler that doesn't do autoboxing properly. Looks like OP hit this error.

Comment: @Ingo - yap. Java < 1.5. My complete answer below

Comment: Thanks for the help, I fixed it, somehow it compiled but the code that I changed wasn't even near the problem, I assume it's one of those unexplainable bugs. Compiler compliance level = 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called autoboxing - the process of converting a primitive (int in this case) to its Object represantation (Integer in this case), automatically. More on autoboxing and unboxing [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/auto-boxing-and-unboxing-in-java-be.html).

Autoboxing was introduced in Java 1.5. So check that your project's compiler compliance level is set to 1.5 or above (Project properties -> Java compiler).